# Session/cookie users getting periodically logged out

Tags: php, mysql, session, session-cookies

My users have been getting logged out from my site. This happens when when someone logs in from another device. I looked into it and noticed someone from a remote IP has been able to log into my website as different users.

I do not know if I am intentionally being targeted, or if it is somehow an error in my code. I would like to know how to properly set up session cookies in a secure manner to prevent this from occurring.

1. **My cookies are HTTP only**
2. I also don't believe it is a man-in-the-middle attack, since **multiple users from different areas are getting logged out**. My website is SSL secured.
3. I don't believe it is a brute force attack. Sometimes when I log in, **within 30 seconds I am logged out again** and the remote IP is logged in.
4. I don't believe he has access to any passwords. Everything is **hashed in the database** and the only thing stored on the client is the session HTTP ONLY cookie token.

I am very stuck.

Here is my **login script** that checks the user's credentials and sets the session:

```php
//database connection is $db_connect

//Creates a random String
function generateRandomString() {
    $length = rand(25, 30);
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
    $charactersLength = strlen($characters);
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, $charactersLength - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

//Grab email, password, IP address
$email_attempt=strtoupper(preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9\.\@\_\-\+]#i', '', $_POST['e']));
$password_attempt=$_POST["p"];
$user_IP = preg_replace('#[^0-9.\:]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));


//Call the database
$sql = "SELECT password, userID FROM user_data WHERE email='$email_attempt' LIMIT 1";
$query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0)
{

    //Get the ID and hashed password from database
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $password_db=$row["password"];
        $userID_db=$row["userID"];
    }


    //Verify Login using password verify
    if(password_verify($password_attempt, $password_db)==true){

        //remove any previous sessions for the user
        $sql = "DELETE FROM user_sessions WHERE userID='$userID_db'";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);


        //Clear any current cookies from client
        if(isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["token"])) {
            setcookie("user", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), '/');
            setcookie("token", '', strtotime( '-5 days' ), '/');
        }
        session_destroy();


        // Set Session data to an empty array
        $_SESSION = array();


        //create a new token, set new session and cookies 
        $token=generateRandomString();
        $_SESSION['user'] = $userID_db;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
        setcookie("user", $userID_db, strtotime( '+3 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);
        setcookie("token", $token, strtotime( '+3 days' ), "/", "", "", TRUE);


        //Hash the token to store in the database
        $token_hash=password_hash($token, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

        //Store session into database
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_sessions 
            (userID, session_token, IP, loginDate) 
            VALUES 
            ('$userID_db','$token_hash','$user_IP', '$current_date')";

        $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);

        header("Location: dashboard.php");
    }

    else
    {
        echo 'wrong_credentials';
    }
}
```

Here is my code to **evaluate a user** and see if they are logged in by examining the session and cookies;

```php
//start session
session_start();

$user_ok = false;
$clientID = "";
$token = "";
$user_IP = preg_replace('#[^0-9.\:]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));

if(isset($_SESSION["user"]) && isset($_SESSION["token"])) {
    //Get session
    $clientID = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['user']);
    $token = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['token']);


    // Verify the user with session data
    $user_ok = checkUser($db_connect,$clientID,$token,$user_IP);



} else if(isset($_COOKIE["user"]) && isset($_COOKIE["token"])){

    //Set session from cookie
    $_SESSION['user'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['user']);
    $_SESSION['token'] = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_COOKIE['token']);


    //Get session data
    $clientID =  preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['user']);;
    $token =  preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_SESSION['token']);

    // Verify the user
    $user_ok = checkUser($db_connect,$clientID,$token,$user_IP);
} 




// User Verify function
function checkUser($db_connect,$user,$token,$ip){

    //Grab the session
    $sql = "SELECT session_token FROM user_sessions WHERE userID='$user' AND ip='$ip' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, $sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($query)>0){

        $row=mysqli_fetch_row($query);

        $token_hashed=$row[0];

        //compare token given and hashed token
        if(password_verify($token,$token_hashed)==true)
        {
            return true;
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    } 

    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So my question: Is this code secure enough?

How can I be more secure?

Also if you have any idea of what is happening in this puzzle please let me know, as I am getting *destroyed*. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm curious: ``$sql = "SELECT password, userID FROM user_data WHERE email='$email_attempt' LIMIT 1";`` is this enough to prevent sql injection in PHP?

Comment: Use prepared statements to protect against SQL injection, not ad hoc string cleaning.

Comment: If the hacker has privileged access to the server, they could be deleting the session files.

Comment: I think you're saying that the hacker is *detecting logins* and responding to them.  If that is true then at minimum they have compromised some part of the network between client and server.  (They could detect establishment of an SSL connection and infer a login from that, even if they couldn't eavesrop on the secured data.)  Most likely, however, they have compromised the server itself.

Comment: "This happens when when someone logs in from another device. I looked into it and noticed someone from a remote IP has been able to log into my website as different users."  This is a serious design flaw in your system anyway.  It's *incredibly* common for people to have multiple IP addresses, even through a single session.  You'll see this often in larger corporate environments where there are multiple gateways to the internet.  There are also people who switch between WiFi and mobile.  And, IPv6 users often use differing addresses for privacy.

Comment: "My cookies are HTTP only, so they cannot be read through JavaScript. I believe this eliminates XSS attacks (correct me if I am wrong)."  Yeah, you're definitely wrong about that.  XSS issues and how your cookies are setup are fairly unrelated.

Comment: "I don't believe it is a brute force attack. Sometimes when I log in, within 30 seconds I am logged out again and the remote IP is logged in."  What do your logs say is happening here?

Comment: Your method of escaping for SQL is seriously flawed.  No doubt one of the many bots scanning web servers for flaws has stumbled across your code.  Use prepared/parameterized queries, always, no matter where the data comes from.

Comment: Someone could inject a user ID and delete everyone's session this way, just an FYI.  I'm not going to spend a half hour trying to figure out the exact string to poke in, but it certainly looks plausible, since you're also re-using data from the first query and running it in your `DELETE` query... again with no escaping!

Comment: @Barmar Thank you, I'll change it. I understand that is best practice, I thought it would be sufficient enough because the preg_replace gets rid of anything that could escape the string. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Brad Thank you for all your feedback. I'll address the flaws you pointed out ASAP. Also, since XSS attack is back on the list, I'll look further into that.

As for the SQL, I'll switch this over to prepared statements. The rest of the site uses it, I thought it would be sufficient because the preg_replace() gets rid of characters that can escape the string. I know now that isn't best practice. 

As for injecting a userID and deleting sessions, I don't believe that is possible because the user needs to successfully log in before any session gets deleted.
Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I realized that the problem lies with trying to anchor a session to a single IP address.

We have CloudFlare running on our site, so `getenv('REMOTE_ADDR')` is sometimes returning CloudFlare's IP address instead of the client IP address. This was causing the logouts.

But I thought I could answer my own question based on the comments. To make the script more secure and stop periodic logouts, I should:

1. **Always use prepared statements** to protect against SQL injection
2. **Don't tie sessions to IP addresses** because they may change (especially if on mobile)

*Occam's razor is the problem-solving principle that essentially states that simpler solutions are more likely to be correct than complex ones.*

Comment: Not sure what web server you're using, but there's generally a way to set a list of trusted upstream proxies, in which case your web server will use the request header value of `X-Forwarded-For` for the remote address it sends to PHP.